# Count the number of occurrences of a word in a text file Linux

Tags: grep

I have a text file and I want to count the number of occurrences the word Orange or orange appears in the text file. orange or Orange should not be part of a word(i.e. "oranges","orangeade", etc).

I was thinking about using grep.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -wo '[Oo]range' filename | wc -l
```

Here the `-w` makes it only match whole words; the `-o` makes it split each occurrence of a match on the same line into its own line and suppresses other output, and the expression will match "Orange" or "orange".

(If you want it to be wholly case-insensitive, and also match "ORANGE" and "OraNGe", etc., you can add the `-i` flag and simply use `'orange'` for the pattern.)

This is then passed to `wc` which counts the words. Since each is on its own line you could use `wc -l` or `wc -w` and the results will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` `g` modifiers on `match` operator :

```
perl -lne 'push @C,/\b[Oo]range\b/g;}{print ++$#C' file
```

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` will find and count (`-c` key) only know patterns. So if you are interested how many times a word *orange* appears in the text:

```
grep -c -e "\borange\b" file
```

But if you are interested in building a dictionary, with unknown set of words - you would need to switch to `awk` or `perl`.

Comment: Pretty sure the `-c` option counts lines only, even if `-o` is used. This isn't going to give the right number if "orange" occurs multiple times on the same line.